# Regarding singular points of a fiber bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibre-bundles

I had asked this question at math.stackexchange but couldn't find any answer; so I'm posting it here.

Let $X$, $Y$ be two projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, where $Y$ is smooth, and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an etale locally trivial fiber bundle, with fiber a variety $F$. Is there a relation between the singular locus of $F$ and the singular locus of $X$? i.e. does the relation $F_{sing}= X_{sing}\,\cap\,F$ hold true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, your $F$ is a particular fiber of $f$? In this case, yes. Your equality can be checked locally for the étale topology, so you can assume $X=Y\times F$, in which case the result is clear.

Comment: @abx : yes, $F$ is a particular fiber. Can you please give some ideas on how to see it, even in the trivial bundle case? I don't understand how to find the singularities of a product .

Comment: $Y$ is smooth, so the singular locus of $Y\times F$ is $Y\times \operatorname{Sing(F)} $.